# Adonis not showing custom error for Route Validator

Tags: javascript, validation, adonis.js

I have the following route:

```
  Route.resource("veiculos", "VeiculoController").validator(
    new Map([[["veiculos.store"], ["StoreVeiculo"]]])
  );
```

and my validator file looks like this:

```
'use strict'

class StoreVeiculo {
  get rules () {
    return {
      vei_placa: 'required',
    };
  }

  get messages () {
    return {
      'required':  'Placa do veiculo nao foi enviada',
    };
  }
  
}

module.exports = StoreVeiculo
```

I'm expecting to receive this error message: "Placa do veiculo nao foi enviada" but I'm receiving the default "Validation failed. Make sure you have filled all fields correctly" instead.

Yes I'm sending a POST request to /veiculos endpoint.

P.S: I'm using adonis v4 and followed the steps here:
https://legacy.adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/validator#_route_validator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I needed to add an async method called **fails** to my Validator class:

```js
  async fails(errorMessages) {
    return this.ctx.response.status(400).send(errorMessages[0].message);
  }
```

This will ensure that the customer message I defined on **get messages()** will be returned.

According to my tests, it doesn't display all errors you might have in your request for once.

My Final validator class looks like this:

```js
'use strict'

class StoreVeiculo {
  get rules () {
    return {
      vei_placa: 'required',
    };
  }

  get messages () {
    return {
      'required':  'Placa do veiculo nao foi enviada',
    };
  }

  async fails(errorMessages) {
    return this.ctx.response.status(400).send(errorMessages[0].message);
  }
  
}

module.exports = StoreVeiculo
```